# How can I execute concurrent HTTP requests in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

In Paw if I have a long running request and attempt to invoke another I'm presented with a dialog that says `Stop request? A request is currently running.` with the options `Cancel`, `Stop` and `Stop & Send`. How can I keep the first request running and invoke another without canceling the first request?

Comment: Hey Jeremy! That would be super nice indeed, but not yet supported :( it's on the roadmap for a long time, though.

Comment: Coming soon to a Paw update near me?

Comment: Can't give you a timeframe for now. But it will be included in Paw.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri any update on this one?  I love Paw.  I can send a group of requests that are all dynamically linked.  Now want to send the SAME group at the SAME time X 5.

Comment: We have an update coming soon that will allow the automatic send of requests that depend on each other (via dynamic values pointing to previous requests). Though, not yet the concurrent sending – we could actually do it quite easily, I'll keep this mind for sure! Thanks!

Comment: That's be great. This is still a feature I look forward to.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri - was this feature implemented?

Comment: Unfortunately not, or not yet. We've made plenty of other additions and improvements that were a lot more requested by users. It's still in our minds though :)

Comment: I want it too :-) Paw is such an beautiful app to work with, but this is an important feature. E.g. if I want to test if my app actually supports multiple running requests at once, or if it queues internally, or if I just don't want to wait for my app to return from some expensive request... Is there any workaround for that? E.g. can I run multiple requests if they are in different projects? Or projects have to wait for each other in queue too? I didn't test that yet

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri I still do not see this feature in Paw 4.0 aka RapidAPI. Is this planned anymore? Parallel execution test IMHO a must have and can be the feature to make RapidAPI go ahead of Postman.

Comment: I'm looking forward to this feature and it is now the year 2023.
@SumitSahoo But I have a workaround by moving some requests into another project, as they can run in parallel in different projects.

Comment: @Finn Wish it could be supported natively.