# Parallel (automated) requests in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I need to do parallel requests or request that come fast after each other to test some API functions in a software.

Can Paw make the same requests every 300ms, for example, without me spamming the CMD+Enter buttons.

Comment: Just found this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747268/how-can-i-execute-concurrent-http-requests-in-paw. Still would love to be able to automate request executing fast after each other.

Comment: Yes, it still isn't possible yet, unfortunately! But we keep that in mind for sure!

Comment: @MichaMazaheri, any possibility to have this feature in a foreseeable future?

Comment: Hopefully yes. We have two more major features to release before that though (being team syncing and assertion testing).